# jQuery Ajax POST - getting "InternalError: too much recursion"

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which I want to post using an Ajax call in jQuery, but I'm getting an error of "too much recursion" in FireFox. It also fails in Chrome so it's not just an issue in FF. The form contains a couple of text inputs and some hidden fields with values that should be posted back on submit.

The form posts successfully without the Ajax call, i.e. using the standard submit button to post the form, but I want to post without posting back the page. The form sits within a jQuery dialog if that makes a difference.

At the moment I'm just trying to see if the call succeeds or fails rather than do anything useful following the call.

There are other similar calls in the project I'm working on that work in pretty much the same way and they have been working as expected. I'm quite new to all this but can't figure out what's wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

```
 $("#formID").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(html){
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, err){
                    console.log(xhr.statusText);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(err);
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: comment out the `data: $(this).serialize(),` line and see if the error goes away. (Yes it will cause an issue with the server)

Comment: Do you get the call on the server? Does it hit your server function? Or your server function returns something but it deosn't come back to the clint?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses...@epascarello - removing that line didn't change anything unfortunately, still the same error. @artm - it doesn't look like the server function is being hit, although as I say it definitely is being hit without the ajax call. I've tried changing the data, the url and the type (even though the call wouldn't work then anyway) and I still get the same error, it doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

here is the working fiddle it is working fine
may be the problem is your jquery version or maybe it will conflicting with othere jquery

`jsfiddle.net/nc97jt52/`

Comment: Thanks for proving that it should work. Unfortunately I still get the same error. I've cleared down everything from the form except the submit button, changed the form's action attribute to simply 'url' as in your fiddle and still I get the recursion error. Really not sure what's going on here, it could be something else conflicting as you suggested - I'll keep looking into it. Have tried clearing browser cache, restarting app server etc. but nothing changes. Thanks

Comment: you should have to debug your jquery by using console.log() and alert() so that you can identify that where the problem actually exist

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the end. On my page I'm including other page templates and modules, one of which was referencing the same .js file that I was referencing on my page. This is what caused the error.

I removed the reference to the template which was linking the same file as it wasn't actually needed and that resovled the issue. Thanks for the help all